# How can I fix a Ratcave Import Error, how can I avoid issues like this in the future?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, numpy-ndarray

I just installed Ratcave yesterday, and have been trying all day to get it to work. My test file is a file that only contains:

```py
import ratcave
```

It throws the same error no matter what I do:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ratcave as rc
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ratcave\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import resources
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ratcave\resources.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .camera import Camera
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .physical import PhysicalGraph
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ratcave\physical.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import coordinates
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ratcave\coordinates.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from ._kdtree import *
  File "C:\Users\drvlw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_kdtree.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._ckdtree import cKDTree, cKDTreeNode
  File "_ckdtree.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.spatial._ckdtree
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
```

How can I fix this?
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling and some other things but everytime I run the file it does the same thing.

Comment: It could be the issue is related to either NumPy or SciPy. What versions of those do you have installed?

Comment: I have NumPy 1.21.5, and SciPy 1.10.0.